# calling javascript code from aspx.cs file

Tags: javascript, .net

I need to run a piece of javascript code, and based on the result of that function, i need to execute something in .net

I tried the following method to execute the javascript code from the aspx.cs file

```
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
    (GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript: hola( ); ", true);
```

When I go into debug mode though, and I put a breakpoint in the javascript code, the program never gets there. Thus I believe the above method to call javascript is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please decide if you need to run Java or JavaScript code... There are some "minor" differences...

Comment: Try with following SO discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484978/clientscript-registerstartupscript-not-working

Comment: Try using other conventional methods like console log or alert to confirm that your code block is not running for sure. Also, I believe that "hola();" should suffice.

Comment: So just to be clear, I can put .js file that contains hola() in the solution, and this should theoretically work?